# Event tracking code to Freeform generated form

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, tracking

Running Expression engine **v2.1.3**.. I know we should update..

I have to say that I am not a developer, but I need a small help here. I have been asked to add a tracking code to a form.

This code:

```
onSubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ClientA NO Landingpage', 'Button', 'Call me']);"
```

To this form:

```
{exp:freeform:form
   collection="Ring meg"
   notify="someemail@someemail.com"
   required="phone1"
   form:class="ringmegform"
   return="{if user_language != 'no'}{user_language}{/if}/aktiviteter/ringer"
   output_json="yes"
   ajax="yes"
}
```

This form uses the default template.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: try this:https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/form/#form_attribute_name